Flutter - Passing args into new page
I'm having some trouble trying to solve this problem.
I've page called ContactDetails, that receives an argument "currentContact" and builds ContactInfo layout, sending the currentContact into the layout.(this was done trying to understant the problem).
The problem is that when I click on the dropdownButton the ContactInfo layout is rebuilt losing all updates done on other fields.
If I comment the args, and build the ContactInfo with the commented currentcontact, that behaviour doesn't happen.
Does anybody knows why?
class ContactDetails extends StatelessWidget {
   ContactDetails({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //PageArgs args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as PageArgs;
    final Contact currentContact= ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Contact;
    //bool isUpdate=args.isUpdate;

   /* Contact currrentcontact= new Contact(
        Company: 1,
        Responsible: "",
        Name: "",
        Email: "",
        MobileNumber: 0,
        InternalNumber: 0,
        InternalFix: 0,
        Perfil: 7,
        CardID: 0,
        isPerson:false,
        Department: "",
        DeviceModel: "Alcatel 3080",
        IMEI: 0,
        Visibility: true,
        Notes: "");*/

    return Contactinfo(currentContact: currentContact, isupdate: true);
  }

ContactInfo partial layout
class Contactinfo extends StatefulWidget {
  Contact currentContact;
  bool isupdate;


  Contactinfo({super.key, required this.currentContact, required this.isupdate});

  @override
  State<Contactinfo> createState() => _ContactinfoState();
}

class _ContactinfoState extends State<Contactinfo> {
class Contactinfo extends StatefulWidget {
  Contact currentContact;
  bool isupdate;
  Contactinfo({super.key, required this.currentContact, required this.isupdate});

  @override
  State<Contactinfo> createState() => _ContactinfoState();
}

class _ContactinfoState extends State<Contactinfo> {
late int userCompany;
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userCompany = widget.currentContact.Company;
    }
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("LO Backoffice")),
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Form(
              key: formstate,
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                        flex: 2,
                        child:UserCompany(updateCompany: _updateCompany,currentCompany: userCompany)
                    ),
]))));}
}

UserCompany widget
class UserCompany extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function updateCompany;
  final int currentCompany;

  UserCompany({super.key, required this.updateCompany, required this.currentCompany});

  @override
  State<UserCompany> createState() => _UserCompanyState();
}

class _UserCompanyState extends State<UserCompany> {
late int selectedvalue;
late List<DropdownMenuItem> listCompanies;
int i=0;

@override
  void initState() {
    selectedvalue=widget.currentCompany;

   listCompanies= bo.instance.companylist.map((Company)
    {
      i++;
      return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: i,
          child: Text(Company.companyID)
      );
    }).toList();

        super.initState();
  }

  // Generating dropdown items
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Building User Company");

    return DropdownButton(
      /*decoration: InputDecoration(
        label: const Text("Empresa"),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      ),*/
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      //focusColor: Colors.transparent,
      isExpanded: true,
      items: listCompanies,
      value: selectedvalue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value != null && value != selectedvalue) {
          setState(() {
            selectedvalue = value;
          });
          widget.updateCompany(value);
        }
      }
    );
  }

}
